# How do I create a random number generator, that each time it is called upon, returns a different value?

Tags: vb.net, random

I've been trying to do this so I can create a maths problem game, with all random numbers so the game can continue for aslong as the user would like to.  However I am currently using this:

```
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim approval As Integer = rand.Next(0, 9)
```

which every time it is called upon, returns the exact same digit.

I was hoping that this would return a different number each time, but after printing it a few times in the same run, I realised that it doesn't and returns the same number.

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` object each time. Create a single one and reuse that. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-random-ctor): if _two Random objects are created in close succession, they are instantiated using identical seed values based on the system clock and, therefore, they produce an identical sequence of random numbers_

Comment: If you need a non repeating RNG (ie each number should appear only once) create a random permuation of numbers `1..n` for example using the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithim and then iterate over that permuation.

Comment: For the record, I down-voted this question because any question that is answered in the documentation doesn't need to be asked here. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation first. It's usually just a press of the F1 key in VS away, so no excuses. Not only that, this question has already been asked and answered on this very site, so you ignored the instruction to search the site for similar questions too. There are a few things that you should always do before posting a question here and either of those two would have given you the answer. Keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score -1):

This creates one Random instance.  Used Form in this example.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Shared PRNG As New Random ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim approval As Integer = PRNG.Next(0, 9)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Down voted?  Really?

Answer (score -2):

Define a random start value for the function e.g.

```
Dim rand As New Random(system.datetime.now.second)
```

can complicate as you like. Limitation to be an Integer value.

Comment: That won't help. The Random class already uses the current time as a seed by default but to a finer accuracy than that. If the default implementation doesn't work, this can't. The issue is not the seed but the creation of multiple instances.

Comment: @jmcil You misunderstood the question. When you use Random without an argument this will provide the same wequence. This can be changed by declaring an argument of it.

Comment: No, I did not misunderstand the question. You just don't know how the `Random` class works. When you create an instance without specifying a seed, it uses the system time, just as it says in the documentation. If you create multiple instances in quick succession then the time won't change so the seed won't change. Your example uses a lower resolution than the default so it will be even worse. How does the idea of providing a random seed help when the point of doing this in the first place is to generate a random number? Where do you think that random seed would come from?

Comment: There's really no point to providing a seed value when creating a `Random` object in order to make it more random. The point of that option is to make it less random, i.e. you can ensure that you generate the same sequence of "random" numbers on multiple occasions by specifying the same seed, so it enables you to test code under the same set of circumstances multiple times.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding the Randomize() somewhere early on in the project

```
Randomize()
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim approval As Integer = rand.Next(0, 9)
'
```

Comment: Nope. `Randomize` is only relevant if you're calling `Rnd`, which the OP is not. Each time you call `Randomize` is like creating a new `Random` object and each time you call `Rnd` is like calling `Next` on that object. Calling `Randomize` repeatedly followed by `Rnd` has exactly the same problem as creating a new `Random` object repeatedly followed by calling `Next`.